# Force re-read GUI property bound in XAML

Tags: wpf, user-interface, refresh, dependency-properties

Maybe it's a simple thing in WPF, can somebody help?

XAML:

```
<GroupBox Header="{Binding Path=Caption}" Name="group">
```

C#:

```
//simplified code
bool _condition = false;
bool Condition
{
    get  { return _condition; }
    set  { _condition = value; }
}

public string Caption
{
    get  { return Condition ?  "A" : "B"; }
}
```

GroupBox is displayed with "B". Fine.
But later we change `Condition= true` , and I want the GroupBox to refresh itself, so read out the Caption again, which will be "A".

How can I do that the simplest way?
Thanks

Comment: It seems this is what I need, let me investigate, and return, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface on your ViewModel.

Then in the setter of Condition you would call OnPropertyChanged("Caption") to inform xaml binding mechanism that your property has changed and it needs to be reevaluated.

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // These fields hold the values for the public properties.
    bool _condition = false;
    bool Condition
    {
        get  { return _condition; }
        set { 
                _condition = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Caption");
            }
    }

    public string Caption
    {
        get  { return Condition ?  "A" : "B"; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property.
    // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName
    // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```